# How can I plot observed and expected frequency from long series data in python

Tags: statistics, frequency-analysis

I have observed data which is given in link below:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2rkXkOkG7ExbFpuSlNJazJoaVE

from this data I tried make plot of observed and expected frequencies by assuming the normal distribution. Can any one help me to figure-out this problems?

Comment: The link you provided asks for permission, please add some relevant example data to your post and set the link viewable by anyone.

Comment: @alessandro I hope this link will work https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2rkXkOkG7ExbFpuSlNJazJoaVE/view?usp=sharing